# USSD in ZTE MF833T

Tags: linux, ubuntu, modem, zte

The [ZTE MF833T](https://www.imei.info/phonedatabase/90379-zte-mf833t/) modem directly runs as USB Ethernet but is not detected by Modem Manager GUI. I have to manage settings using its IP address `http://192.168.0.1/`.

Is it possible to send [USSD requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) with this ZTE MF833T modem?

[image: modem-settings]

Comment: What about if you create the connection manually inside NetworkManager? - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492651/modemmanager-cant-set-the-interface-settings?noredirect=1#comment906325_492651

Comment: A) Ask your service provider how to use it to 'check your balance'. If they tell you how, then it will accept USSD requests. B) Also, keep your eye on https://www.imei.info/phonedatabase/90379-zte-mf833t/#comments for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

send USSD request in ZTE MF833T modem?
Try This For USSD http://192.168.0.1/index.html#ussd

Comment: Baisnabi, your answer has attracted negative attention. I wonder if you can address some possible concerns. First, you've simply repeated part of the question, which isn't necessary. Second, you start your answer with the phrase "try this", which implies a low level of confidence on your part. Is this solution something you've tried personally, or seen somewhere directly? Third the answer you've given appears to be a web page, in particular an anchor on the index page. Do you have any evidence that the modem's page has anchors on it pointing to USSD functionality?